# endless redirect HAPROXY

Tags: unix, web, haproxy

I helped to deal with misfortune, I began to learn haproxy in connection with the working need. The task of entering a URL like https://my.server.ru/ is to immediately redirect to a directory like https://my.server.ru/SoftOnIt/ I did it, but there is a problem, when clicking on the link and after a redirect, the page begins to infinitely refresh or redirect. I attach the full config of my haproxy. haproxy -c -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
`Apr 30 12:55:12 localhost haproxy[3124]: 192.168.1.92:53661 [30/Apr/2020:12:55:12.000] https-proxy~ 1c_path/s1 0/0/15/9/24 200 18570 - - ---- 2/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /SoftOnIT/ru_RU/ HTTP/1.1"`
there’s nothing too ...
As far as I understand the problem with `http-request set-path /SoftOnIT/ if 1c`
me need to do something like checking - If the current url is already required then do not redirect.
Help to figure out the logic. 
**And sorry for google translator =)**

````
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    ssl-server-verify none
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 4096

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

#-----------------------------------------------------------
frontend http-proxy
    bind *:80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc } #редирект на https
    default_backend 1c_web
    ########Для установки и обновления letsencrypt##############
    acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
    use_backend letsencrypt-backend if letsencrypt-acl
#---------------------------------------------------------------
frontend https-proxy
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.server.ru/my.server.ru.pem
    acl 1c hdr_end(host) -i my.server.ru
    http-request set-path /SoftOnIT/ if 1c
    use_backend 1c_path if 1c
    default_backend 1c_web
#---------------------------------------------------------------
backend letsencrypt-backend
    server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:8888
#---------------------------------------------------------------
backend 1c_web
    mode http
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server 1cweb 10.255.10.26:80 check cookie 1cweb
#---------------------------------------------------------------
backend 1c_path
    server s1 10.255.10.26:443 ssl```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check not only the host header also the path.

My suggestion

```
frontend https-proxy
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.server.ru/my.server.ru.pem

  acl 1c hdr_end(host) -i my.server.ru
  acl 1c_path path_beg /SoftOnIT

  http-request redirect code 301 location https://%[req.hdr(host)]/SoftOnIT  if !1c_path

  use_backend 1c_path if 1c !1c_path
  default_backend 1c_web
```

Comment: Good afternoon, your method does not redirect to my.server.ru/SoftOnIT/ = (
The IIS homepage opens.
In the haproxy logs: ```haproxy[15307]: 192.168.1.92:55558 [07/May/2020:09:23:04.962] http-proxy http-proxy/<NOSRV> 0/-1/-1/-1/0 301 109 - - LR-- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1" and haproxy[15307]: 192.168.1.92:55561 [07/May/2020:09:23:04.979] https-proxy~ 1c_path/s1 0/0/14/5/19 200 938 - - ---- 3/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"```

Comment: I have added the redirect to /SoftOnIT